# Is it a mandatory to wrap a System.Diagnostics.Process with using when I don't know whether the executable being invoked is managed or native?

Tags: c#

Is it a mandatory to wrap a `System.Diagnostics.Process` with `using` when I don't know whether the executable being invoked is managed or native?

**Code 1:**

```
        Process p = new Process();

        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);

        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-interaction=nonstopmode " + inputpath;
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = dir;

        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdflatex.exe";

        p.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
```

or

**Code 2:**

```
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {

            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);

            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-interaction=nonstopmode " + inputpath;
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = dir;

            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdflatex.exe";

            p.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
```

?

### Edit 1

Let consider the code 1 above, what will happen when the `pdflatex.exe` gets crashed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `using` clause has nothing to do with whether the process that you started is managed or not. You use it because the `Process` class implements [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) (via the `Component` class).

The `using` clause will automatically call the [`Dipose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w.aspx) method when the program leaves the clause's scope. This will free any unmanaged resources that the `Process` class may have allocated to launch your executable, whether is was managed or not.

It is very strongly recommended that you always call `Dispose` on instances of classes that implement `IDisposable` either manually or by instantiating them in a `using` clause.

Comment: What happens when the executable invoked by the process gets crashed  and I don't wrap the process with `using`?

Comment: which one crashes, the one that is starting the new process or the process that got started?

Comment: the `pdflatex.exe` gets crashed for example.

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact implementation, but there might be a process handle that needs to be freed by the instance of `Process` even if the process crashed, otherwise it might remain allocated until the garbage collector finalizes your instance of `Process`.

Answer (score 0):

Either way should be ok. If an unmanaged code calls this exe/dll then any resource handling and error trapping must be done there.